# AJAX JSON RPC ERROR: [object Object]

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, perl, json-rpc

I am trying to call a JSON RPC function via CGI with perl. But getting the following error.

> > ERROR: [object Object

Can someone please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

**Test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

                                $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "cgi-bin/server.cgi",
                                        data: '{"version": "1.1", "method": "echo", "params" : ["Hello World"]}',
                                        processData: false,
                                        async: false,
                                        timeout: 30000, // msec
                                        contentType: "application/json",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        success: function(response){
                                                $("body").append( "<br>SUCCESS: " + response.version );
                                                $("body").append( "<br>version: " + response.version );
                                                $("body").append( "<br>result: " + response.result );
                                                $("body").append( "<br>OK" );
                                        },
                                        error: function(response){
                                                $("body").append( "ERROR: " + response );
                                                $("body").append( "<br>" );
                                        }
                                });


});
</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**server.cgi**

[root@ip-172-31-0-164 cgi-bin]# cat server.cgi 
    #!/usr/bin/perl

```
use JSON::RPC::Server::CGI;
use strict;

my $server = JSON::RPC::Server::CGI->new;

$server->dispatch('MyApp')->handle();
```

**MyApp.pm**

```
[root@ip-172-31-0-164 cgi-bin]# cat MyApp.pm 
#!/usr/bin/perl

package MyApp;

use base qw(JSON::RPC::Procedure); # Perl 5.6 or more than
use strict;

sub echo : Public {    # new version style. called by clients
     # first argument is JSON::RPC::Server object.
     return $_[1];

}

sub sum : Public(a:num, b:num) { # sets value into object member a, b.
     my ($s, $obj) = @_;
     # return a scalar value or a hashref or an arryaref.
     return $obj->{a} + $obj->{b};
}

1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an `Internal Server Error` (in plain text, not JSON) returned by `server.cgi`. We can't see the message (you didn't post any logs), so you'll need to check your web-server logs to find out what the server-side error is.

One reason could be that you don't have a reasonable version of `JSON::RPC` installed.

In any case, you're getting `ERROR: [object Object]` because you're trying to call `.toString()` (you've done this implicitly by doing `"..."+response`) on the XHR object (which you've named `response`) in your `.error` callback definition:

```
error: function(response){
  $("body").append( "ERROR: " + response );
  $("body").append( "<br>" );
}
```

The method signature for `.error` is `function error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)`. You'll likely want to change this to:

```
error: function(xhr, status, error){
  $("body").append( "ERROR: " + error );
  $("body").append( "<br>" );
}
```

Additionally, you're not handling JSON-RPC level (as opposed to HTTP-level) errors. In your `.success` handler you should examine `response.error`. If this is non-null then a JSON-RPC level error (say an exception in one of the `MyApp` subs) has been thrown.

You could handle it like this:

```
success: function(response){
  if (response.error) {
    $("body").append( "<br>ERROR! " );
    $("body").append( "<br>version: " + response.version );
    $("body").append( "<br>message: " + response.error.message );
    $("body").append( "<br>code: " + response.error.code );
    $("body").append( "<br>FAIL" );
  } else {
    $("body").append( "<br>SUCCESS!");
    $("body").append( "<br>version: " + response.version );
    $("body").append( "<br>result: " + response.result );
    $("body").append( "<br>OK" );
  }
}
```